# Does ZFC + the Axiom of Constructibility imply the nonexistence of inaccessible cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

In ZFC set theory, does adding Constructibility imply the nonexistence of inaccessible cardinals like it does the nonexistence of other types of higher cardinals?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: What effort? Sure, this is something one can look for online, but this is not a "how do I prove the following equality" type of question. What kind of effort are you looking for from the OP?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The one you mentioned: to have tried to do an online search.

Answer (score 6):

Not unless they are inconsistent altogether.

Inaccessible cardinals, Mahlo cardinals, weakly compact cardinals, and in fact much more, are all downwards absolute to $L$, in the sense that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible, then it is inaccessible in $L$, and same for Mahlo or weakly compact and so on.

In fact, many equiconsistency results utilize this, for example: if $\omega_2$ has the tree property, that implies that $(\omega_2)^V$ is weakly compact in $L$.

Answer (score 3):

*This should really be a comment, but it's too long.*

As Asaf said, any inaccessible cardinal is also inaccessible in $L$, hence the existence of an inaccessible cardinal is consistent with ZFC+V=L iff it is consistent with ZFC. The idea "V=L disproves large cardinals" (which you may have heard) is true *in a sense*, but without context it's highly misleading.

To try to clear things up, let me briefly explain why by contrast the existence of a measurable cardinal *does* contradict V=L:

First of all, note that being a measurable cardinal is a more complicated property than being an inaccessible cardinal. $\kappa$ is measurable if **there exists** some $\mathcal{U}$ such that [stuff]. Just because such a $\mathcal{U}$ exists doesn't at first glance imply that there is such a $\mathcal{U}$ **in the specific substructure** $L$. By contrast,  inaccessibility has no such "witness requirement." Precisey: inaccessibility, Mahlo-ness, etc. are $\Pi_1$ properties, and all such properties are absolute from $V$ to $L$. Measurability on the other hand is $\Sigma_2$.

Now this doesn't show that measurables are inconsistent with V=L, just that the argument for consistency that we used for inaccessibles doesn't apply here. To show that measurables are in fact inconsistent with V=L, we need a more complicated argument. Roughly, we say:

- Let $\kappa$ be the least measurable cardinal. *(Exercise: a countably closed ultrafilter on the least measurable $\kappa$ is in fact $\kappa$-closed. This is not true in general.)*
- If $\mathcal{U}$ is a $\kappa$-closed ultrafilter on an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we can form the "[ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of the universe" $\prod_\kappa V/\mathcal{U}$. It takes a bit of thought to define this properly, but it can be done.
- Since $\mathcal{U}$ is countably closed, the ultrapower is well-founded (think by contrast about an ultrapower of a well-founded model of ZFC by a *non*-countably-closed ultrafilter), and it's clear from the definition (once written out carefully) that it's set-like, so [it is isomorphic to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma) an [inner model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model) $M$ of $V$.
- Let $j:V\rightarrow M$ be the embedding induced by this construction (the composition of the Mostowski collapse and the ultrapower embedding). This map $j$ is an elementary embedding, so $M\models j(\kappa)$ is the least measurable cardinal.
- But it's not hard to show that $j(\kappa)>\kappa$. *(Think, in the ultrapower, about the equivalence class of the identity function $id:\kappa\rightarrow\kappa$ - this corresponds to an element of $j(\kappa)$, but is above each constant sequence $x\mapsto \alpha$ for each $\alpha\in\kappa$.)*. This means that $M\not=V$, since $M$ and $V$ disagree about the least measurable.
- So **if there is a measurable cardinal, then there is a proper inner model of ZFC**. But $L$ is the minimal inner model of ZFC, and so measurable cardinals can't exist in $L$.

The motto here is:

> Big large cardinals - measurables and above - imply that the universe is "wide" (specifically, that there are lots of nontrivial inner models). This contradicts V=L since $L$ is "thin."

By contrast, an inaccessible cardinal is "all about height" in a precise sense (namely, inaccessibility is a $\Pi_1$ property). $L$ is no shorter than the whole universe! **The naive idea that "large cardinals = high infinities" misses the real deep features of strong large cardinal axioms**.

Comment: I call them "large large cardinals" and "small large cardinals", then there are "small large large cardinals" and "large small large cardinals", and so on and so on... :)